# How to format double in Salesforce Apex

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I want to display double in format such as "12.30" but it display "12.0" in salesforce apex.
can any one help me?

Answer (score 5):

VisualForce uses the [java.text.MessageFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) conventions for formatting. Here's an example. Replace the `MyDouble` variable with your own.

```
<apex:outputText value="{0,number,0.00}" >
    <apex:param value="{!MyDouble}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the 12.30 as an int and then cast it back to double. Casting it to an int truncates the fraction.

```
double i = 10.345;
system.debug('this is i '+ i);
system.debug('this is i after fixing '+ (double)(integer)i);
```

gives:

```
10:04:26.129 (129990000)|USER_DEBUG|[16]|DEBUG|this is i 10.345
10:04:26.130 (130080000)|USER_DEBUG|[17]|DEBUG|this is i after fixing 10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating a field then we have to define it's decimal places. Try specifying that decimal number to 2. It will work.